# Programatically Getting POP3 Message Unique Id and Message Size

Tags: php, email, zend-framework, codeigniter, pop3

I need to access a POP3 email account and obtain the the list of messages' unique id and its corresponding file size. I'm using CodeIgniter and have access to Zend libraries. Trying to do something similar to the LIST command. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look into "[Reading Mail Messages](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html)" in the Zend Framework documentation.
`Zend_Mail_Storage_Pop3` is what you are looking for.